# Update the JLabel's label text during the event - Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Basically I want change the JLabel's Label text during on-click the button
'Generate PDF Record Book'

[image]

From the previous example says:

```
label.setText("new value");
```

when I do that, the label value doesn't change at all, please give me some directions, thanks

initialize();

```
JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("513 k bytes");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(407, 713, 151, 14);
    frmViperManufacturingRecord.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
```

On button **Generate PDF Record Book** click

```
        JButton btnGeneratePdfHeader = new JButton("Generate PDF Record Book");
    btnGeneratePdfHeader.setMnemonic('G');
    btnGeneratePdfHeader.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("513 k bytes");

            //java.io.File file = new java.io.File(strdfile);
            //lblNewLabel.setSize(file.length());
            //System.out.println(file.length());

            String fileSize = file.length() + " k bytes";
            System.out.println("I am here");

            lblNewLabel.setText("new value");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new `JLabel` when pressing the button and then set the text of that label to "new value"

```
final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("513 k bytes");
lblNewLabel.setText("new value");
```

rather than changing the text of the label on your UI. You will need to call `setText("new value")` on a reference to the label you've already added to the UI instead. For instance, that label would neeed to be a field in your UI class, eg `final JLabel fileSizeLabel` and you would set that labels text by calling

```
fileSizeLabel.setText("new value");
```

inside the buttons action listener.

Comment: Please read my answer again. You didn't do what I suggested at all. the only thing you did is set the unnessesary JLabel to `null` which produces a `NullPointerException` when calling a method on it.

Comment: Thanks @Marv, based on your comments, have [achieved](http://i.imgur.com/domHHMZ.png) it, Thank you so much for pointing out the mistake and making me to learn and fix the problem. Thanks